# Strange? Primes and Palindromes have no business being in this Place?

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, lateral-thinking, number-sequence, no-computers

$1$

$1$,$2$    Good easy start

$1$,$2$,$4$ As expected

$1$,$2$,$4$,$8$ I know it is going to be easy

$1$,$2$,$4$,$8$,$16$ why is he giving this? I got it!

$1$,$2$,$4$,$8$,$16$,Prime ...oops!..why is it here?

$1$,$2$,$4$,$8$,$16$,Prime, Odd...sure this is odd

$1$,$2$,$4$,$8$,$16$,Prime,Odd,Palindrome...this sure is strange and wierd?

Maybe, oeis will help me..oh no..

Looks like I have to put my thinking cap and get a solution for those 3 missing members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, oeis will help me..oh no.. <sub>this puzzle is spoiled</sub>

Answer is:

> [31 (prime), 57 (odd), 99 (palindrome)](https://oeis.org/A000127)

Key to this is:

> Maximal number of regions obtained by joining $n$ points around a circle by straight lines

Comment: Oh no..I didn’t check it right..when I checked,,I got 17 hits..I didn’t find..u cannot win them all..thx

Comment: Sure..everything fits ..p..o..pal